# Marketing Cloud Reports on Campaign based on the bounce rate

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, custom-reports

I'm looking for different possibilities of creating  report in MC for a campaign based on the Bounce rate%.

ex : I want to setup a report for xyz campaign where bounce rate is more than 5%.

I know it's possible in Discover reports under - Discover email sending performance report.(Since SFMC is not going support this in the coming future)

Also, in Tracking reports it's possible with - Campaign Email Tracking ( Triggered Send Tracking data is not included)

I know it's also possible with help of _Bounce Data View, but I'm not sure how to get the bounce rate% in the SQL query for a specific campaign.

Please do let me know if there are any other way through which it can be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: Datorama Reports for marketing cloud should replace the discover reporting for this use case

Comment: Thanks @EazyE for your comment and answer. Just a follow-up question - Do we have to use the Advance functionalities of Dataroma report in this case?. As Advance Dataroma reports is the paid solution, so was curious to know about it.